# Server Independent WebSocket Implementation

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, tyrus

I am trying to find a solution for a Server Independent WebSocket implementation, Tomcat inbuilt WebSocket API is good but it's not running in Weblogic and other servers .
I found a solution with Tyrus API , but all examples of Tyrus is done with grizzly web server , where it starts a separate server with a new port to accept ws:// request , but it has another option which is ServerContainer, where it will work with any Servlet Container web server and will use the existing Server port only, but unfortunately no example i found .. I am looking forward to any other options also ...

Comment: so you have an http server that does not support websocket? or you don't like its websocket?

Comment: why are you looking for an implementation? All Java EE 7+ compatible appservers must have JSR 356 implemented - as long as you stick to the official API, you should be fine.

Comment: @PavelBucek I am new in Websocket and confused pls give me a small explanation .. Are u saying that our websocket application can run on all EE7+ servers who supports websocket ? Our company application need to run on Tomcat-7,8(Main target) , JBoss-EWS , Weblogic , WebSphere .. And we about to add websocket feature into it .. Do we need anything like tyrus ? or the code which running with tomcat inbuilt websocket will run on other mentioned server also ..

Comment: Tyrus is just an implementation. If your app will be run on Java EE 7+ compatible appserver and if you will stick to official API (see JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket), you should be able to migrate among Java EE 7+ appservers without any issues - that's why Java EE exists..